# Why is text on the SVG logo disappearing at the IOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, svg, frontend

Text in the logo doesn't appear at the IOS (iPhone). What is cause?
Image: [SVG logo](http://egrn-servis.ru/wp-content/uploads/egrn-servis-ru.svg)

Comment: It doesn't show up for me using Safari on my computer. It seems that the text is white. I assume you are putting it on a background with a colour other than white?

Comment: The text is black, you can see it at the Windows or Android

Comment: It just got the text to appear in Safari by installing the font Roboto on my computer. If you open the svg in an image editor (i used Affinity Designer) you can covert the text to shapes. Then the iPhone wouldn't need to try and use the font (which it doesn't have installed either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the lack of the correct font on the system that is causing it to disappear.

Converting the text in the svg to shapes worked for me: [this is the logo that I converted to test with](http://swift7media.com/egrn-servis-ru-shapes.svg). I tested it by using Charles Proxy and mapping locally the image request to your current logo.

Hopefully you can use this updated logo.

Comment: I've used this logo and everything is ok now. Thank you

Comment: Thats great, no problem